# How to make size_hint_x start from 0.2 instead of 0 in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, sizehint

I have many columns to show using layout5. Since the app will be displayed on different screen sizes, I used layout5.bind(minimum_width=layout5.setter('width')) to set the width. Notably, Layout5's parent is scroll3 with pos_hint={'x':0.2,'y':0.02}. This means my columns start showing from x=0.2. Problem: layout5.bind(minimum_width=layout5.setter('width')) calculates the minimum width from 0 instead of 0.2, so I can't see all columns.

Question: how can I make sure that the `layout5.bind(minimum_width=layout5.setter('width'))` takes into consideration the fact that the parent widget (scroll3) x-axis starts at 0.2?

Note:

1. I have put asterisks on the parts of the code that one should focus on.
2. When running the code, just substitute `Screen1.csv` with any csv file on your machine.

Full code:

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
import pandas as pd
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivymd.uix.anchorlayout import MDAnchorLayout
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRoundFlatButton
from kivymd.app import MDApp



class Screen1 (Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Screen1, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # Reading Data
        data1 = pd.read_csv('Screen1.csv')

        # row range
        rows1 = range(3, 29)

        # column range
        cols1 = range(4, 74)


        layout0 = GridLayout(cols=1, rows=1, size_hint=(0.18, 1.79))
        layout0.bind(minimum_height=layout0.setter('height'))
        self.add_widget(layout0)
        label0 = Label(text="Train Station           Platform", bold=True)
        layout0.bind(minimum_width=layout0.setter('width'))
        layout0.add_widget(label0)

        # Creating the Stations names and their respective platforms
        cols10 = range(1, 3)
        layout10 = GridLayout(cols=len(cols10), rows=len(rows1), size_hint=(1, None), row_default_height=50, spacing=10,
                              row_force_default=True)
        layout10.bind(minimum_height=layout10.setter('height'))
        # 2.65
        scroll1 = ScrollView(do_scroll_x=False, do_scroll_y=True, size_hint=(0.20, 0.84),
                             bar_color=(0, 0, 0, 0), bar_inactive_color=(0, 0, 0, 0))
        scroll1.add_widget(layout10)
        self.add_widget(scroll1)

        for row in rows1:
            for col in cols10:
                selected = str(data1.iloc[row, col])
                label10 = Label(text=selected, color=(1, 1, 1, 1), opacity=1)
                layout10.add_widget(label10)

        # Creating the back button
        layout1 = MDAnchorLayout(anchor_x='left', anchor_y='top')
        self.add_widget(layout1)

        button1 = MDRoundFlatButton(text='Back', line_color=(1, 1, 1, 1), text_color=(1, 1, 1, 1), _min_height=30,
                                    _min_width=100)
        #button1.fbind('on_press', self.Screen2)
        layout1.add_widget(button1)

        # Creating the title label
        layout2 = GridLayout(cols=1, rows=1, size_hint_y=1.93, size_hint_x=1.1)
        self.add_widget(layout2)

        label2 = Label(text="KwaMashu to Durban to Umlazi", bold=True, font_size=20)
        layout2.add_widget(label2)

        # Creating the train numbers
        rows2 = range(1, 2)
        layout4 = GridLayout(cols=len(cols1), rows=len(rows2), size_hint_x=None, size_hint_y=1, col_default_width=100,
                             col_force_default=True, spacing=10)
        layout4.minimum_width = len(cols1)
        layout4.bind(minimum_width=layout4.setter('width'))
      
        scroll2 = ScrollView(do_scroll_x=True, do_scroll_y=False, size_hint_y=1.74, pos_hint={'x': 0.20, 'y': 0.02},
                             bar_inactive_color=(0, 0, 0, 0), bar_color=(0, 0, 0, 0))
        scroll2.add_widget(layout4)
        # pos_hint = {'x': 0.20, 'y': 0.02},
        self.add_widget(scroll2)
        for row in rows2:
            for col in cols1:
                df1 = data1.iloc[row, col]
                label8 = Label(text=str(df1), bold=True)
                layout4.add_widget(label8)

        # Creating the timetable label

        
#Important***
        layout5 = GridLayout(cols=len(cols1), rows=len(rows1), size_hint_x=(None), size_hint_y=None,
                             col_default_width=100, col_force_default=True,
                             row_default_height=50, spacing=10, row_force_default=True)
        layout5.bind(minimum_height=layout5.setter('height'))
        layout5.bind(minimum_width=layout5.setter('width'))

#Important***
        scroll3 = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, 0.84), pos_hint={'x': 0.2, 'y': 0.02},
                             bar_inactive_color=(0, 0, 0, 0), bar_color=(0, 0, 0, 0))
        scroll3.add_widget(layout5)
        self.add_widget(scroll3)

        for row in rows1:
            for col in cols1:
                df = data1.iloc[row, col]
                label5 = Label(text=str(df), color=(0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 1))

                layout5.add_widget(label5)

        # Timetable and train numbers (X move together, not Y)
        scroll3.bind(scroll_x=lambda instance, value: setattr(scroll2, 'scroll_x', scroll3.scroll_x))
        scroll2.bind(scroll_x=lambda instance, value: setattr(scroll3, 'scroll_x', scroll2.scroll_x))

        # Timetable and Train Stations names (Y move together, not X)
        scroll3.bind(scroll_y=lambda instance, value: setattr(scroll1, 'scroll_y', scroll3.scroll_y))
        scroll1.bind(scroll_y=lambda instance, value: setattr(scroll3, 'scroll_y', scroll1.scroll_y))

class SuperApp (MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style='Dark'
        screen_manager=ScreenManager()
        screen_manager.add_widget(Screen1(name='Screen1'))
        return screen_manager

if __name__=='__main__':
    SuperApp().run()
```

Comment: please look and show the line which raises the error message .. it seems you give a nimber but it expect a unicode string as parameter.

Comment: @Malo, this is the line that raises the error: size_hint_x= 
(0.2, 1). 

Given the fact that this does not work, is there another way to achieve my objective?

Comment: Looking quickly into the doc .. it seems size_hint_x expects a single int like 1, not a pair/tuple like the one you gave. Otherwise use  size_hint without the _x

Comment: @Malo, indeed, you are correct.  Does this mean I can not make my size_hint_x start from 0.2 (instead of 0)?

Comment: Perhaps you should be asking how to accomplish what you want to see in your app. It is not clear what you expect to see if you could do what you are asking.

Comment: @JohnAnderson, great point. Let me explain:

I have many columns to show using layout5. Since the app will be displayed on different screen sizes, I used `layout5.bind(minimum_width=layout5.setter('width'))` to set the width.

Notably, Layout5's parent is scroll3 with `pos_hint={'x':0.2,'y':0.02}`. This means my columns start showing from x=0.2.

Problem: `layout5.bind(minimum_width=layout5.setter('width'))` calculates the minimum width from 0 instead of 0.2, so I can't see all columns. Hence, I asked if there's a way to specify that the x-axis of the layout starts from 0.2, not 0.

Comment: Another way of thinking about the solution is to ask: how can I add 0.2 to whatever my `layout5.bind(minimum_width=layout5.setter('width'))` calculates as a minimum_width needed to show the columns.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @JohnAnderson, I have rephrased my question - and added sufficient code to run on your machine. 

Another way of thinking about this: 
It is like having an Excel sheet that has tens of rows and columns. Now, the first row and first column contain the titles. Given this, you do not want the first row and column to disappear when you scroll up or to the left. (In Excel, you would use `Pane Freeze` to achieve this.)

This is exactly what I am doing on my app except that when I scroll to the left, not all columns show. This is because the parent widget's (scroll3) width starts at 0.2 not 0.

Comment: When I run your code, I can see all the columns. The biggest issue I see is if some entries are wider than the forced default of `100`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson, do you see all the columns even if you have more than 71 columns?

Comment: I just noticed that your `scroll3` has `size_hint=(1, 0.84)`. This means that `scroll3` width is the entire width of your `Screen1`. However, your `pos_hint` puts the `scroll3` at an `x` value that is 20% of the `Screen` width. This means that the right 20% of `scroll3` is off the `Screen`. Try changing the `size_hint` of `scroll3` to `size_hint=(0.8, 0.84)`. You may have similar issues elsewhere.

Comment: @JohnAnderson, perfect! This works exactly the way I want it to. Thank you, your help is much appreciated.

Could you please post it as an answer so that I can upvote and accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scroll3 has size_hint=(1, 0.84). This means that scroll3 width is the entire width of your Screen1. However, your pos_hint puts the scroll3 at an x value that is 20% of the Screen width. This means that the right 20% of scroll3 is off the Screen. Try changing the size_hint of scroll3 to size_hint=(0.8, 0.84). You may have similar issues elsewhere.